# Is it possible to send messages via Telegram Bot to a specific phone number (not chat_id/username)?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I understand that this question has been asked before, but those topics are dated 4 years ago, so I wonder if anything changed.

TL;DR:
I understand the concern that sending messages via phone number would make users vulnerable for spam. But there is something I discovered that makes me reconsider this. If I /start a chat with Telegram Bot, chat_id is generated. Interesting thing is, this chat_id is the same for my conversations in other chats. I might be wrong here, but it seems that spam issue should be handled in a different way. Thus, I wonder if there is a possibility to send messages straight to user's phone number.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. Each user's ID is unique and not changing during conversation/chats. But you can't send the message to user if he did not accepted it by starting your bot as i know. Also, phone number can be shared only from user side. You can't find users by phone number, at least, official api doesn't provide such methods.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! (I can't upvote it though, it is my first question and I have less than 15 reputation)

Comment: Np, @MaxShmurygin :)